# how to create barriers between dynamically added and modified views

Tags: java, android, kotlin, border

I add View objects programmatically and then have the ability to change their X and Y by dragging them across the Layout,but they have a problem where one object can go beyond the boundaries of another. I need it to rest against another view and not go beyond it. How to do it?
here is my code:

```
    private fun drawobject(context: Context?) {
        val r: Resources = getResources()
        val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 100F,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()).toInt() // Convert mm to px
        val objectconteiner: LinearLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar_container)
        var ViewLayoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            100, 20)
        var imageView:View = View(context)
        imageView.setLayoutParams(ViewLayoutParams)
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        var initialX:Float? = null
        var initialY:Float? = null
        var initialTouchX:Float? = null
        var initialTouchY:Float? = null

        imageView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->

            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    initialX = event!!.getX()
                    initialY = event!!.getY()
                    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
                    //Log.e("211", "$initialX")

                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    binding.Hsc.setSwipeable(false) //ban on scrollview movement
                    binding.Vsc.setSwipeable(false) 
                    initialTouchX = (event!!.getX() - initialX!!)
                    initialTouchY = (event!!.getY() - initialY!!)

                    var actualX = imageView.x + initialTouchX!!
                    var actualY = imageView.y + initialTouchY!!
                    imageView.setX(actualX!!)
                    imageView.setY(actualY!!)
                    //Log.e("2", "$px")
                    //Log.e("2", "$actualX") 
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    //Log.e("2", "gh")
                    binding.Hsc.setSwipeable(true)
                    binding.Vsc.setSwipeable(true)
                }

            }
            true

            }

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        objectconteiner.addView(imageView)

    }
```

The view is loaded in LinearLayout, XMl:

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar_container"
       android:layout_width="100mm"
       android:layout_height="100sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"
       android:background="@color/back">
   </LinearLayout>
```

As I understand it, you need to set a limit when setX,Y but how to get the X and Y boundaries of another object. I write in Kotlin but I also understand java, if you know how to solve this question, answer java or kotlin.

Comment: You dont want your ImageView to go outside the LinearLayout? You have reference to it : objectconteiner, so take its position x,y, width and height, and update actualX and actualY before calling setX and setY.

Comment: without any conditions this too, but the biggest problem is creating borders for two or more added views, the function itself draws a view when a button is pressed, when adding 2 or more views and dragging them, you can allow one to overlap another surface, how to get rid of from this ?

Comment: As I understand it, I will need to create a function that counts all the boundaries of other elements and compares them with the boundaries of the one being moved, creating a loop of iterating through already added objects (since there is no limit on adding), but perhaps there is a simpler method that I don’t know about?